# Iphone communication between 2 cell phones

Tags: iphone, xcode, messaging

I am developing an application for an Iphone and I need to know if there is a way to communicate between 2 iphones either through some kind of messaging or anything similar to that.  Kind of like a yahoo messanger.
Thanks
Saro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read about [GameKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and it's p2p connectivity. Question with some example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1049393/277021)